# Want bluetooth sniffer tool for Windows

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am working on a bluetooth project and require some software that could capture the bluetooth packets and then can view (using same or different software) or analysis the packets captured.
Can any one help me to give names of softwares that could solved the issue in windows operating system.

Comment: I know some commercial solutions that well supports BT sniffer. I'm a mobile app developer and sometimes our partner sends `.cfa` sniffer file. After googling, It's from this company: http://www.fte.com/support/examples.aspx.